# Ember 2.5 ember-cmi-mirage trying to get a subset of collection

Tags: ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

Using ember 2.5 and ember-cli-mirage 0.2)

In my mirage/config.js , I am trying to get a subset ofa collection, for pagination purpose) using the slice() function

```
var books = schema.book.all().slice(startItem, endItem );
```

but I get an error:

```
schema.book.all(...).slice is not a function
```

I tried also , same error

```
var books = schema.book.all();
var items = books.slice(startItem, endItem );
```

Here is my mirage/config.js
        export default function() {
            ....
          this.get('/books', function(schema, request) {

```
        const pageNumber = request.queryParams['page[number]'];
        const pageSize = request.queryParams['page[size]'];

        const startItem= (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
        const endItem = (pageNumber * pageSize) - 1;

        var books = schema.book.all().slice(startItem, endItem );

        ....

        return books;
      });
    }
```

It seems that slice() is a function of ArrayProxy..  however this may not help as with a JSONAPISerializer

I'm a little bit lost as all exampels I can google relate to Ember 1.13 and not Ember 2.5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Collection is array-like, but not a true array. Precisely for this reason, in the next beta release we'll expose a `.models` property which has the underlying array.

For now, try calling `.toArray()` on your `schema.book.all()` collection, and then calling `slice` on it.

To take advantage of the Serializer layer, make sure to return a new Collection from your handler:

```
import Collection from 'ember-cli-mirage/orm/collection';

this.get('/books', (schema, request) => {
  let books = schema.book.all().toArray().slice(...);

  return new Collection('book', books);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , that's what I tried ... and  effectively I get a subset 'items' n but I cannot return it as it's not a Collection ... anyway to convert it back into a Collection ??

Comment: yes, try `import Collection from 'ember-cli-mirage/orm/collection'; 'return new Collection('book', books)`

Comment: youre welcome! If the answer helped could you mark it correct for future readers?